# remove <p> from $description variable before storing in database(laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, fckeditor

i am getting value of input tag i.e an textarea converted into Fckeditor as:

```
"<p>bgfbgfbgf</p>\r\n"
```

i want to store my value in database after `<p>` tags get removed.

how should i remove the `<p></p>` tags from my value.
can anyone help me with this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove tags and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php) to remove `\r\n` if needed:

```
strip_tags(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this will solve your problem
$text = "<p>bgfbgfbgf</p>\r\n";
$replace = array('<p>','</p>');
$text =  str_replace($replace,'',$text);
```

This will only remove p tags.

Answer (score 0):

To remove only the `<p>` and `</p>` and nothing else use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) and the following [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```
$html = "<p>bgfbgfbgf</p>\r\n";
$string = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/is', "", $html);
```